# Should Linux kernel build with -Werror?

Tags: linux, compiling, arm

I've always built the Linux kernel with `-Wall -Werror` to make sure I don't miss any warnings I introduce during developement.  However it seems that as of 4.18 the default ARM build won't complete with `-Werror` due to an unimplemented syscall.  If I remove `-Werror` the build completes successfully.

Is it reasonable to expect the kernel to build with `-Werror` enabled?  Should this be reported as a bug?

Steps to reproduce:

```
# Set PATH and CROSS_COMPILE to appropriate toolchain
# export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
# export PATH=${TOOLCHAINDIR}/bin:${PATH}

ARCH=arm KCFLAGS="-Werror" make defconfig KBUILD_DEFCONFIG=ti_sdk_am3x_release_defconfig
ARCH=arm KCFLAGS="-Werror" make zImage
```

Error encountered:

```
$ ARCH=arm KCFLAGS="-Werror" make zImage
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
<stdin>:1332:2: error: #warning syscall io_pgetevents not implemented [-Werror=cpp]
```

I've found other reports of this same failure ([like this](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org&q=subject:%22linux%5C-next%5C%3A%20build%20warning%20after%20merge%20of%20the%20vfs%20tree%22&o=newest&f=1)), but no clear solution.